# Change Scenes after Interstitial (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, interstitial

Here is the code that runs when the restart button is tapped. The game resets the score, plays and interstitial ad, and then goes back to the game scene.

Right now it does not wait for the interstitial to be exited before changing the game scene.

```
  if restartButton.contains(pointOfTouch) {

            score = 0

            displayAd()



            let sceneToMoveTo = GameScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)

        }
```

Comment: I tried `interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial)` but it did not work. Although I am not sure if i put the right thing between the parentheses.

Comment: What you are describing is what your code currently does. So what you could do is to notify the scene when ad is finished / exited. To do that you can post a notification and add a scene as an observer of that notification (and run the appropriate code accordingly).

Comment: Do you have a tutorial link, that you could point me to for this?

Comment: this is the notification i am currently using to call my ad `func displayAd() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "loadAndShow"), object: nil)
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to do was include a wait function, that way the ad is shown on the screen before the scene even transitions.

```
 func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
         let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
 }
```

And then placed scene changer within the delay function like so

```
 delay(2.0) {
    self.changeScene()
 }
```

The 2.0 is the time in seconds so this is saying that the code will wait 2 seconds and then run the change scene function. When the ad is exited the scene is now changed.